# I do not get prime-decomposition! Please help!

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, products, group-isomorphism

So this is a group theory question and I am particularly interested in part b. I  don't see how they are equivalent. I am told that is this is because $C_9 \ncong C_3 \times C_3$, but I was wondering why. Is it that $C_4 \ncong C_2 \times C_2$? If somebody could explain exactly how to break these things down so we can see what is isomorphic to what I would be EXTREMELY grateful! much love. xx

[image: Group theory question]

Comment: What are these C-groups?

Comment: It it is the multiplicative group of complex nth roots of unity. x

Comment: Alternately, $C_i$ is the cyclic group of order $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_4$.

The four elements of $C_2\times C_2$ are $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)$. Now let's look at their doubles:

- $(0, 0)+(0, 0)=(0+0, 0+0)=(0, 0)$.
- $(1, 0)+(1, 0)=(1+1, 0+0)=(0, 0)$.
- $(0, 1)+(0, 1)=(0+0, 1+1)=(0, 0)$.
- $(1, 1)+(1, 1)=(1+1, 1+1)=(0, 0)$.

That is, **every element of $C_2\times C_2$ has order $2$**: double it, and you get the identity.

By contrast, let's look at $C_4$, which has four elements: $0, 1, 2, 3$. If we double (say) $1$, we get $2$; this is not the identity! So $C_4$ has elements which are **not of order $4$**.

This is enough to show that $C_2\times C_2\not\cong C_4$; proving this is a good exercise. *HINT: show that if $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ have different orders, then no map sending $g$ to $h$ can be an isomorphism.*

Similarly, $C_3\times C_3\not=C_9$. More generally, if $a$ and $b$ are not coprime (= have factors in common; e.g., $4$ and $6$ are not coprime), then $C_a\times C_b\not=C_{a\times b}$. By contrast, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime (= no factors in common; e.g., $15$ and $8$ are coprime), then $C_a\times C_b=C_{a\times b}$. This is another good exercise, and - while significantly more difficult - will reveal a lot about how products of groups behave.

Comment: I just noticed your comment stating that your definition of the cyclic groups isn't in terms of modular arithmetic, but rather complex numbers. I think this is a more opaque definition, so I'm sticking to the one via modular arithmetic; it will help you a lot, I think, to realize that your $C_p$ is just addition mod $p$ in disguise.

Comment: So  why exactly does the formula not work here $|G \times G| = |G_1| |G_2| $? Are we not using the direct product in this case?

Comment: that is fine! My supervisor does what he feels like regarding this.

Comment: It is indeed true that $\vert G_1\times G_2\vert=\vert G_1\vert\vert G_2\vert$ always; however, just because two groups have the same size doesn't mean they're isomorphic! For instance, my answer shows that  $G_4$ and $G_{2\times 2}$ have the same size, but are not isomorphic. One way to think about this is the following: two sets are "basically the same" if they have the same number of elements, but a group is more than just a set - it also is (or contains, or involves, or ...) a rule about how the elements of that set relate to each other (I'm talking about the group operation here).

Comment: thank you so much!!! You are a legend!